# How to load qml file from resources, using QtQuick 2 Controls

Tags: qt, resources, qt5, qtquick2

I have created Qt Quick 2 Controls project, added resource, placed my qml-file inside resource and added alias to this file. Now I'm wondering, why does next code can't load qml-file as main qml-file:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include "qtquick2controlsapplicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Application app(argc, argv);

    QString fileInResource(":main/mainQml");

    QFile f(fileInResource);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        qDebug() << "No file";
    } else {
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        qDebug() << f.readAll();
    }

    QtQuick2ControlsApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(fileInResource);
    viewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Since in case of `QFile` usage, it reads file correct and output whole file, but `viewer` said:

> file:///path/:main/mainQml:-1 File not found
>
> QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
>   Error: Your root item has to be a Window.`

How to make `viewer` load my qml-file?

---

**UPD:** Added minimal working example -- [download it here](https://db.tt/lujtrpgH)

Comment: Try qrc://main/mainQml

Comment: Frank, this way I got worse result: `No file 
file:///path/qrc:/main/mainQml:-1 File not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in

```
void QtQuick2ApplicationViewer::setMainQmlFile(const QString &file)
```

It uses

```
setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(d->mainQmlFile));
```

for setting source, and `QUrl::fromLocalFile` messes up the path. Just change it to

```
setSource(QUrl(d->mainQmlFile));
```

and everything works.

UPD:

In your example it's actually `component.loadUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(d->mainQmlFile));`, line 80.

Answer (score 2):

No file file:///path/qrc:/main/mainQml <-

try change the code like below and make sure main.qml file exists in resource .qrc file

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("utils", &qmlUtils);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
```

or like this if you are not using the QQmlApplicationEngine

```
 Application app(argc, argv);
 QString fileInResource("qrc:///main.qml");
```